# is it possible to have an if function in a foreach loop in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, foreach, codeigniter-3

Is it possible to have an if statement in a `foreach` loop? for me it doesn't work, I have a function like this:

```
<?php 
     foreach($userdetail_list as $row):
?>
 <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged']=! TRUE){ ?>
 <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/ChatboxController"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary bs" value="Bericht sturen"></input> </a>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <tr>
     <td><h2><?php echo $row->voornaam;?> <?php echo $row->achternaam;?></h2></td>
     <td><p><?php echo $row->woonplaats;?></p></td>
     <h3>Over mij:</h3><td><?php echo $row->beschrijving;?></td><br>
     <h3>Contactgegevens:</h3>
     <td><p><?php echo $row->email;?></p></td>
     </tr>
<?php endforeach;  ?>
```

So I'm getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>       Severity: Parsing Error
>       Message: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)
>       Filename: views/profiel_user.php
>       Line Number: 38
>       Backtrace:

So it says i didnt end the if statement correctly.

Comment: try to check the code thoroughly while posting a here...that is simple and error also reflecting clearly what exactly the issue is.........try to maintain indentation  to avoid like this simple issues

Comment: Ok sir thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `}` closing bracket instead `endif;`

```
<?php } ?>
```

You are not using `if ( .. ) :`

Get more details from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) , to check how these syntax works.

Comment: yeah great and simple

Answer (score 0):

error in this line. missing `:`.... In codeigniter not used `{`. [if condition in codeigniter please read manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/alternative_php.html)

i have fixed this issue

`<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged']=! TRUE): ?>`

if you don't want to used alternative PHP syntax in Codeigniter then follow this sample code

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged']=! TRUE){ ?>
.......

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `endif` into `}`. Try to use this code.
What you need to do is just copy and paste this code. All done.

```
<?php 
foreach($userdetail_list as $row){ ?>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged']=! TRUE){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/ChatboxController"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary bs" value="Bericht sturen"></input> </a>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
    <td><h2><?php echo $row->voornaam;?> <?php echo $row->achternaam;?></h2></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->woonplaats;?></p></td>
    <h3>Over mij:</h3><td><?php echo $row->beschrijving;?></td><br>
    <h3>Contactgegevens:</h3>
     <td><p><?php echo $row->email;?></p></td>
 </tr>
<?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code,

```
<?php 
   foreach($userdetail_list as $row){
      if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged']=! TRUE){ ?>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/ChatboxController"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary bs" value="Bericht sturen"></input> </a>
              <?php } ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><h2><?php echo $row->voornaam;?> <?php echo $row->achternaam;?></h2></td>
                          <td><p><?php echo $row->woonplaats;?></p></td>
                          <h3>Over mij:</h3><td><?php echo $row->beschrijving;?></td><br>
                          <h3>Contactgegevens:</h3>
                          <td><p><?php echo $row->email;?></p></td>
                      </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have an if statement in a foreach loop. Let me show you a demo here:

```
$myData = array('Gopal'=>'Sharma','Dixit'=>'Prashant');
foreach($myData as $key=>$value){
    if($key=='Gopal'){
        echo "Yes <br/> We can have an if statement in a foreach loop.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

Your issue lies in the syntax of your condition. Replace your opening curly bracket `{` with `:`

`<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged']=! TRUE) : ?>`

See [PHP's Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)